Most suitable statistical model in an unbalanced, repeated-measures, paired observations setting
I've got the following dataset. For every subject, brain data has been recorded across different days, and for each day, in different states (sleep/awake). Data has been recorded in many channels simultaneously, which span different brain regions. Channels are belonging  to different regions and differentiable on the basis of being pathological channels, or not. I have then computed a feature (y) in different frequency bands.
These are my columns:
PatientID | Day | State | Chan | Band | Region | isPhysiological | y
I want to understand whether whether there is a certain brain area (say, frontal lobe) where the difference between physiological and pathological emerges; while in another brain area (say, central) it does not.
Samples are dependent (same subject has observations in Physiological and Pathological class) so ANOVA is not applicable.Also, dataset is unbalanced, and Repeated Measures ANOVA is not suitable.
I would probably use a Linear Mixed Model, using the interaction between regions and phys/path as my main effect; and (at least) subject as my random effect (cause I expect intrisic between-sbj variability).
Something like
$$
y \sim Region*isPhysiological + (1|PatientID) 
$$
I don't care about within-regions differences (i.e., of course frontal will be different from central). What I care about is Physiological/Pathological differences within the same region.
The problem is, I have so many covariates that I cannot pool everything together in the same model due to sample size limitations. So:

How should I deal with all the potential other random effects? States, Days, Channels, Regions.. Cause these ones are also responsible of prior variability.
I am not sure how to treat frequency bands: Should I do a different model for each band? Or should I consider the band as part of the fixed effect in the interaction term? Cause clearly this difference between Physiological/Pathological in a certain region, might only appear in one band.

